# Strange colour cast in Python plt.imshow() image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, keras

I am processing some images (jpegs) using the Keras ImageGenerator. To debug, I display some images during the processing loop:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**datagen_args)
X = np.zeros(4, 224, 224, 3))  # pralloc matrix for storing the images

for i in range(4):      
    img_path = repo + fnam[i]
    image = plt.imread(img_path)        

    plt.imshow(image)  # image looks correct
    plt.show()

    trans_img = datagen.random_transform(image)  # keras ImageGenerator

    plt.imshow(trans_img)  # image looks correct
    plt.show()

    X[i, :, :, :] = trans_img
```

Note that the ImageGenerator does not apply any colour cast. After this has finished, I select one image from X and display it:

```
im1 = X[0, :, :, :]
print(im1.shape)  [224, 224, 3]

plt.imshow(im1) 
plt.show()
```

The resulting image has a strange **blue colour cast**. I have tried various other ways to load and display the images, but they all have the blue cast.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

---

**UPDATE:** This works and shows the image with the correct colourmap:

```
from scipy.misc import toimage
toimage(im1).show()
```

If someone can explain why, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: You may look at the datatypes of `image`, `trans_img` and `im1` (using `.dtype`). I would guess that they differ. If this is the case and you can report the dtype of each, one may find a good explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I have checked and the data type are all the same (ints).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from scipy.misc import toimage

toimage(im1).show()